# How can I display a list of numbers that start with a user input in C# and the .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, .net

```
namespace A3PFJBJLP1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // option 1 by parker farewell
            Console.WriteLine("~ option 1 ~");
            Console.WriteLine("please input a number: ");

            for (int StartingNum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); StartingNum < 20; StartingNum++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(StartingNum);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

So far this is the code I've tried and I can display the numbers in a list, but only if the number is 20 or less when I need to make a list that displays 20 whole numbers that come after the number inputted by the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close. If you start at a number `userInput`, you want to display 20 numbers after it you could update the loop as follows.

```
int userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); // get and store user input
for (int startingNum = userInput; startingNum < userInput + 20; startingNum++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(startingNum + 1); // display number after startingNum
}
```

Comment: thanks man this really helped a lot. my first time actually asking a question on this platform and safe to say definitely going to be using it during  online collage

Comment: It's my first day too. You probably already know this but remember to show your work and ask help in particular places where you're stuck. And "accept" or upvote the answer if it helps!

Comment: for sure will do nbow i just gotta get odd and even numbers to display another calulation

Comment: Consider using `int.TryParse()` to convert the user input to a number. Both `Convert.ToInt32` and `int.Parse` will throw an exception if a user enters an incorrectly formatted number. Bad user input is hardly an *exceptional* condition